# Ubuntu, change to a directory and run a command line when startup

Tags: linux, bash, ubuntu, startup, scrapyd

On a ubuntu server I'd like to CD to one of my directory and then run the command line `scrapyd`

I'm using the following command:

```
(cd /path/to/my/folder/; scrapyd)
```

Which works well.

I now would like to run this command line once my ubuntu server starts. To do so I edited my crontab by adding to it:

`@reboot (cd /path/to/my/folder/; scrapyd)`

But the scrapyd is not running after reboot. I then created `run_scrapyd.sh`:

```
#!/bin/bash
(cd /path/to/my/folder/; scrapyd)
```

And I updated my crontab by the following:

```
@reboot /bin/bash /path/to/an/other/folder/run_scrapyd.sh
```

But still scrapyd is not running after rebooting

Comment: Did you update the full path of `scrapyd` when running in cron?

Comment: @Inian I cannot find the full path, according to the doc: To start the service, use the scrapyd command provided in the Scrapy distribution: scrapyd

Comment: To locate the full path use `which` command.

Comment: it works fine with the full path, thanks guys!